# Make Wysiwyg Use CKEditor CDN

Tags: 7, hooks, wysiwyg, cdn

Is it possible to make the [Wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module use the CKEditor's CDN for delivering the editor to the browser client?

Answer (score 3):

If all you're using the wysiwyg editor is for ckeditor, you can use the [ckeditor module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) instead.

> This module will allow Drupal to replace textarea fields with the
>   CKEditor - a visual HTML editor, usually called a WYSIWYG editor. This
>   HTML text editor brings many of the powerful WYSIWYG editing functions
>   of known desktop editors like Word to the web. It's very fast and
>   doesn't require any kind of installation on the client computer.

you can tell ckeditor to use the CDN in the Advanced settings of the Global Profile:

[image]

Comment: When I go to Configuration all I see is a section called "Content Authoring" and two menu options: "Text Formats" and "Wysiwyg Profile". I looked through all the sections in the Wysiwyg profile but didn't see an advanced settings section.

Comment: @AdamFisher sorry, missed a line when typing - if all you're using wysiwyg for is ckeditor, use the ckeditor module instead and you can do the above

Comment: I did look into that module but some of the modules I plan to use are requiring Wysiwyg so I thought I would kill two birds with one stone. If I have to I suppose I can just live with it being served from my server. I was hoping maybe there was an easy hook for it

Comment: @AdamFisher a quick look around, and in the module files themselves, I see no reference to CDNs anywhere, so I don't think it supports that functionality - you may be forced to use both, or keep the files local